# regarding a certain homomorphism of finite free modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

Consider the following situation: let $(R,m)$ be a local Noetherian ring and $f: F_1 \rightarrow F_0$ a morphism of finite free $R$-modules with $\operatorname{rank}(F_i) = r_i, \, i=0,1$. Suppose that the image of $f$ contains a free direct summand $U$ of $F_0$ of rank $r_1$. How can we prove that $im(f) = U$?

The above situation arose in the proof of Proposition 1.4.12 (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a) in Bruns and Herzog Cohen Macaulay Rings.

Remark: What confuses me is that since $\operatorname{Hom}(M,L \oplus N) = \operatorname{Hom}(M,L) \times \operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$, then we can write $F_0 = U \oplus H$ and so $f=(f_U,f_H)$. Then i don't see why $f_H$ should be zero.

Comment: I'm affraid you didn't show us the whole picture: in the book it is also assumed that $F_1/\ker f$ is free of rank $r_1$.

Comment: @YACP: As i understand, this is assumed to perform the induction step for complexes of length greater than 2. But the authors don't say how they prove that for the case where our complex is $0 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$, i.e. for the first step of the induction.

Comment: I don't undestand your comment: isn't trivially satisfied the first step?

Comment: @YACP: If our complex is $0 \rightarrow F_s \stackrel{f_s}{\rightarrow} F_{s-1} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$, then why is it true that $f_s$ is injective and why is it true that $f_s(F_s)$ is a direct summand of $F_{s-1}$? Why is this trivially true?

Comment: Ah, it is a complex, not a resolution!

Comment: @YACP: Yes... :)

Comment: Then you can use 1.4.9(b) since now you trivially have $I_{r_1+1}(f)=0$.

Comment: @YACP: Why do we have $I_{r_1+1}(f)=0$? If we tensor $f: F_1 \rightarrow F_0$ with $R/m$ then we get  $I_{r_1+1}(f) \subset m$. Then?

Comment: $f$ is an $r_1\times r_0$ matrix between two free modules, right? Then the ideal generated by the $(r_1+1)$-minors of this matrix is...?

Comment: @YACP: right right right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Proposition 1.4.9(b) taking into account that $I_{r_1+1}(f)=0$.